anchor test fails at initialize instruction which initializes token 2022 accounts
I'm writing typescript anchor test code about my initialize instruction, it fails with this error.
       Is initialized!:
     Error: AnchorError caused by account: system_program. Error Code: InvalidProgramId. Error Number: 3008. Error Message: Program ID was not as expected.
Program log: Left:
Program log: fMs6rgUQr9mFRcAShGaSMKfwsMAmwhn3JAjHFtwGj5E
Program log: Right:
Program log: 11111111111111111111111111111111

My initialize instruction looks like below.
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(receipt_token_name: String)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        seeds = [b"fund"],
        bump,
        space = 1024,
    )]
    pub fund: Account<'info, Fund>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        seeds = [receipt_token_name.as_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
        mint::token_program = token_program,
        mint::decimals = 9,
        mint::authority = fund,
        mint::freeze_authority = fund,
        extensions::transfer_hook::authority = fund,
        extensions::transfer_hook::program_id = crate::ID,
    )]
    pub receipt_token_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = admin,
        seeds = [b"receipt_lock", receipt_token_mint.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint = receipt_token_mint,
        token::authority = fund,
    )]
    pub receipt_token_lock_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[program]
pub mod myProgram {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        receipt_token_name: String,
        default_protocol_fee_rate: u16,
        whitelisted_tokens: Vec<Pubkey>,
        lst_caps: Vec<u64>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let fund = &mut ctx.accounts.fund;

        Ok((fund.initialize( // this just stores values
            ctx.accounts.admin.key(),
            default_protocol_fee_rate,
            whitelisted_tokens,
            lst_caps,
            ctx.accounts.receipt_token_mint.key(),
            ctx.accounts.receipt_token_lock_account.key(),
        ))?)
    }
}

The test code is here.
const receipt_token_name = "receiptToken";
const default_protocol_fee_rate = 10;
const whitelisted_tokens = [token1.publicKey, token2.publicKey];
const lst_caps = [new anchor.BN(1000), new anchor.BN(2000)];

const [fund_pda, ] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("fund")],
    program.programId
);
const [receipt_token_mint_pda, ] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from(receipt_token_name)],
    program.programId
);
const [receipt_token_lock_account_pda, ] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("receipt_lock"), receipt_token_mint_pda.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
);

    console.log(fund_pda, receipt_token_mint_pda, receipt_token_lock_account_pda);
    console.log(TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId);

    const tx = await program.methods
        .initialize(
            receipt_token_name,
            default_protocol_fee_rate,
            whitelisted_tokens,
            lst_caps,
        )
        .accounts({
            admin: admin.publicKey,
            // fund: fund_pda,
            // receiptTokenMint: receipt_token_mint_pda,
            // receiptTokenLockAccount: receipt_token_lock_account_pda,
            // tokenProgram: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
            // systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .signers([admin])
        .rpc();
    console.log("Initialize transaction signature", tx);

Fund PDA address is fMs6rgUQr9mFRcAShGaSMKfwsMAmwhn3JAjHFtwGj5E which is shown at Program log: Left: at the error log.
FYI & My Questions
There were some weird thing I couldn't understand.

I used pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>, but there was no token_program id set at the IDL file. So I added the Token2022 program id manually at the IDL. I did this because if the token_program address is not set at IDL, the error message is different. Error: Account tokenProgram not provided. So I added it manually. Why token_program id is not set? Is the token_program format I used is wrong?
I want to use Token2022 program. Is this format right? At some other references, they used Program<'info, Token2022>. Which one is the right one?
The error says system_program id is set to other program id which is fund pda's address. But, I commented out the fund at initialize().accounts() but the error is same. I don't understand what's going on here.
Do I have to input tokenProgram and systemProgram id at initialize().accounts()? Some have input them to accounts(), and some didn't. So, it looks ok not to put them manually, but why some have input them? What's the difference between them?


There's a few questions here, so I'll do my best to answer:

if you're using TokenInterface, it means that your program supports both SPL Token and SPL Token 2022. So when someone calls your program, they need to choose which token program they want to use. But in your case, you likely need to use Token2022 since you're initializing extensions, which are only supported in Token-2022
I think that was answered in question 1
There's something strange going on, because the Initialize struct only allows a string parameter to be passed in, but then the initialize instruction processor expects a lot more parameters. Maybe something's going wrong there?
I think the Anchor client will try to figure out the account addresses if they're not passed in. So in the case of the system program, since your program is explicitly expecting Program<'info, System>, the client can know that you meant to pass that in. Same with the PDAs, it can resolve the addresses automatically.

